# Django Group By all Combinations of ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I'd like to perform a group_by on a ManyToManyField `habit_type = models.ManyToManyField(HabitType, blank=True)`, but not on every single existing element but on the existing permutations. E.g. currently there are 7 existing elements which are referenced to and with the query below it is grouped by each element. I'd like to group by the existing permutations like (1,2), (1,3,5), (1,4,6,7)
But I do not want all possible combinations which would be a little bit too much...

```
result = obj.registration_set.values(habit_type=F('participantpersonal__habit_type'))\
            .annotate(number_personal=Coalesce(Count('participantpersonal__habit_type'), 0))
return result
```

As example I have 6 entries with the habit (1,2) the current output is:

```
{
    "habit_type": 1,
    "number_personal": 6
},
{
   "habit_type": 2,
   "number_personal": 6
}
```

And my wished output is:

```
{
    "habit_type": [1,2],
    "number_personal": 6
},
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is quite complex, so I'm providing my own solution here so that maybe someone else can filter arrays exclusivley:

First to gather all possible combinations I wrote the helper method, which return all the combinations in a given range. In this case, the range is 1 to 7 resulting in 127 combinations:

```
def distinct_combinations(num_range):
    result = []
    for r in num_range:
        comb = list(combinations(num_range, r))
        result.append(comb)
    return [item for sublist in result for item in sublist]
```

For the query, I'm iterating through each combination and for each combination, I'm calculating a counter list (don't know the exact term for it) which counts all ids' minus the one in the currently used combination.

The query itself works like filtering the current combination and then excluding the counter list. E.g. when the field has (1,) then it does not get matched by the combination (1,2) as 2 is part of the counter list.
As then items can be still counted multiple times, the ids of the result will be saved and used for the next queries to be excluded. The result is saved in a custom JSON.

```
    habit_types = list(HabitType.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
    all_combination = distinct_combinations(habit_types)

    result = []
    list_id = []

    ids = list(obj.registration_set.values_list('id', flat=True))
    total_participants = ParticipantPersonal.objects.filter(registration__in=ids)

    for combination in all_combination:
        comb_opposite = list([elem for elem in habit_types if elem not in combination])
        num_pariticpants = total_participants.filter(habit_type=combination) \
            .exclude(eat_habit_type__in=comb_opposite).exclude(id__in=list_id).values_list('id', flat=True)

        list_id.extend(num_pariticpants)
        num_result = num_pariticpants.count()

        json = {
            'habit_type': EatHabitType.objects.filter(id__in=combination).values_list('name', flat=True),
            'num_participants': num_result
        }

        result.append(json)
    return result
```